# can recitation of the quran (ruqya) be used to heal physical ailments?

Tags: spirituality

Hi i was at a mufti Menk lecture the other day and he mentioned that to the best of my understanding and recollection that Quran can be used to heal people from sicknesses. also I have come across narrations which mentions that prophet Muhammed approved the use of Ruqya for scorpion stings. my question is can Quran recitation be used to heal physical ailments and are there any evidences to suggest which verses for which ailments?

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Do not use comments for answering questions. We have the "Answer" field for those.